# HTML5/JS equivalent of a UINavigationController

Tags: javascript, html, navigation

I'm working on an HTML5-based app with an iPad view and wanted to have a list in a sidebar that has navigation nested so that I user could drill down a couple of levels before tapping the desired item in the main view to the right. I don't have a ton of web experience and I'm hoping someone could point me in the direction of a js-based library that would offer such functionality.  The closet thing that I could imagine would be something similar to the UINavigationController in iOS that would allow me to easily push and pop lists of items.

I've explored JQuery Mobile and the closest thing that I could find was the 'nested listview' functionality, which as of version 1.3 is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Mobile](http://api.jquerymobile.com/) has this functionality built in. I would suggest reading through all the documentation. It will give you a better understanding of jQuery mobile and what you can and cant do.

Or if you just want information about the Navigation Model you can read about it [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html).

Finally you can find a demo of it in action [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/pages/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to built it yourself then [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is probably the way to go.

Description from their website:

> A unified, HTML5-based user interface system for all popular mobile
>   device platforms, built on the rock-solid jQuery and jQuery UI
>   foundation. Its lightweight code is built with progressive
>   enhancement, and has a flexible, easily themeable design.